# Digital Logic - Implementing Boolean expression using minimum number of 2-input NOR gates

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-logic, digital-logic, nor

Implement this Boolean expression using a minimum number of 2-input NOR gates. Then, illustrate with a clearly labelled logic circuit diagram.

```
F(w,x,y) = (x+y)(w+y)(x'+y')
         = [(x+y)' + (w+y)' + (x'+y')']' //double negation
         = [y'(x'+ w') + xy]'
         = [y'(xw)' + xy]'
         = [(y+xw)' + (x'+y')']'
         = [(y+(x'+w')')' + (x'+y')']'
```

As far as I know, NOR gate is (x+y)'. From here, I'm confused on how to begin using the result above to produce the logic circuit diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the notation `P ⊥ Q` for `nor`, i.e., for `(P + Q)'`.

Start here:

1)

```
[(y+(x'+w')')' + (x'+y')']' = A ⊥ B
```

where `A = (y+(x'+w')')'` and `B = (x'+y')'`

2)

```
A = y ⊥ D
```

where `D = (x'+w')' = x' ⊥ w'`.

3)

```
B = x' ⊥ y'
```

4)

```
x' = x ⊥ 0
y' = y ⊥ 0
```

Now put everything together:

```
[(y+(x'+w')')' + (x'+y')']' = A ⊥ B
                            = (y ⊥ D) ⊥ (x' ⊥ y')
                            = (y ⊥ (x' ⊥ w')) ⊥ (x' ⊥ y')
                            = (y ⊥ ((x ⊥ 0) ⊥ (w ⊥ 0))) ⊥ ((x ⊥ 0) ⊥ (y ⊥ 0))
```

And I bet you will now be able to draw the circuit.